# How does a eclipse debug mode behave when java code is modified in mid of debug execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When we modify the java code(including the code that is already executed / to be executed) in mid of debug execution how does the eclipse exactly behave?

1. when does the debug pointer move back to the starting of the method that's being executed?
2. When does it will suggest terminating the program?
3. When does it will accept the code changes and proceed further smoothly?

Comment: You mean hot code replace alias HotSwap, which is not an Eclipse, but a Java debugger thing. In Eclipse when saving a changed file, the code will be replaced via HotSwap while debugging. This does not work, if the new code does not compile or a method signature gets modified, since this would require re-solving method calls everywhere. The next time the code is executed, the new code is then used. What do you mean by _debug pointer_?

Comment: Hi howlger, by debug pointer I am referring to debug current instruction pointer.

Comment: HotSwap does not move back. You can use [_drop to frame_](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html#drop-to-frame) for some kind of going back. Keep in mind that Java is a stack machine.